# Sending e-mails to multiple addresses with different pdf attachments

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an Access form with a command button that opens a report and creates .PDF files in a local folder. Each .PDF report has a different name (1234.pdf, 4321.pdf, etc.)  The number represents the employee number and the report is that employee's current leave time balance.  So basically, I end up with about 60 .PDF files in the folder, each one for a different employee.  After creating these .PDF files, I'd like them to be e-mailed to each respective employee with their own .PDF attachment via Access instead of me creating a separate e-mail in Outlook and attaching the file manually. I know how to send one .PDF file attachment to one or more recipients but can't figure out how to send a particular .PDF file attachment individual recipients. I was thinking that perhaps the file could be sent right after it is created and then move on to create the next file, etc.  I don't know.  Below is the code I'm using to create the .PDF files for each employee number.  BTW, the employee number and e-mail address are stored in the same employee table, if that helps.

```
Private Sub CmdAllLeavePDF_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim MyFileName As String
Dim mypath As String
Dim temp As String
Dim sNow As String

mypath = "C:\Users\rbryan_2\Desktop\EDM Reports PDF\"

sNow = Format(Now(), "mmddyyyy")

Set db = CurrentDb()

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT [TblNames.EmpID] FROM [QurEmpLeaveCurrAll]", dbOpenSnapshot)

Do While Not rs.EOF

temp = rs("TblNames.EmpID")

MyFileName = rs("TblNames.EmpID") & " - " & sNow & ".PDF"

DoCmd.OpenReport "RptEmpLeaveCurrAll", acViewPreview, , "[TblNames.EmpID]='" & temp & "'"
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, mypath & MyFileName

DoCmd.Close acReport, "RptEmpLeaveCurrAll", acSaveYes
DoEvents

rs.MoveNext
Loop

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

Beep
Eval ("MsgBox ('PDF FILES CREATED!@Individual Employee Leave Totals Reports Were Successfully Created@In The EDM Reports PDF File Folder.@@',64,' Employee Data Management')")
   
Me!CmdN.SetFocus

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have any bound `Textbox` on the form showing email address? What is the name of the field containing email addresses on table? Can you show us a screenshot of your table?

Comment: There are no bound text boxes on the form, it's just a form with command buttons to print various reports based on various queries.  The table name is TblNames and the field containing the e-mail addresses is called EmpEmail.  The field containing the employee ID is called EmpID.  Does that help any?

Answer (score 1):

As you already have codes to generate `.pdf`files so use below codes to send emails to individual email address with separate pdf. Here `EmpID` is employee number field and `Email` is the field of employee email addresses. If you email field is different name then adjust it.

> **I hope you are aware about `Add References` Microsoft Outlook x.xx Object Library.**

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdSendMails_Click()
Dim oApp As New Outlook.Application
Dim oEmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strEmail As String, strAttachment As String
Dim mypath As String

mypath = "C:\Users\rbryan_2\Desktop\EDM Reports PDF\"
'mypath = "C:\Users\Harun.Rashid\Desktop\My PDFs\"

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT EmpID, EmpEmail FROM TblNames", dbOpenSnapshot)

    On Error Resume Next 'Suppress errors 
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        strAttachment = mypath & rs!EmpID & ".pdf"  'Pdf name exactly as employee ID.
        strEmail = rs!EmpEmail 'Email address from table column.
        
            Set oEmail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            With oEmail
                .Recipients.Add strEmail 'Add email address
                .Subject = "Your subject text here."
                .Body = "Your body text here."
                .Attachments.Add strAttachment 'Attach PDF file.
                '.Send
                .Display 'Use .send to send the mail. Display will show the email editor window.
            End With
            Set oEmail = Nothing
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much Harun, I'll give this a try tomorrow, I don't have Outlook on this computer at home.  I have referenced the Outlook object library and I'm able to send .PDF reports from Access.  I'm just having problems with the other.  I'll be sure to let you know if this works tomorrow.  Thanks again.

Comment: @RPHBryan So, what I will suggest is Make a new button naming `cmdSendMails` and use this code to that button to test either it works or not. If it works then deploy codes with your existing code.

Comment: Harun, with some minor adjustments, the code works great except that it gives me an error and stops if a PDF file does not exist for a particular employee number.  I tried putting Nz in the code but still no luck.  strAttachment = Nz(mypath & MyFileName & rs!EmpID & ".pdf")  Perhaps I'm putting it in the wrong place.

Comment: If it can't find a particular file, I'd like it to go to the next EmpID and not error out.

Comment: @RPHBryan If that is the case then you have to suppress errors by using `On Error Resume Next`. See my edited answer.

Comment: Harun, That worked great.  61 .PDF files created and 61 e-mails generated with separate attachments.  Thank you so much Mate.

Comment: @RPHBryan Glad to know it works. If you found the answer helpful please consider accepting the answer. Tick mark it. Also upvote to answer encourage users.

Comment: @Harun24HR Limit the scope. `On Error Resume Next` just before `Attachments.Add strAttachment` then  return to normal error handling with `On Error GoTo 0`. http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm